# Node Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js

I’m trying to call a Node webservice from an existing app running on Apache.  It’s giving me problems because the app is running on a different port than Node.  I did some searching, and I was able to get it to work by adding a new property to my header response:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  , 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://myHostName:80'    // Added this line
});
```

The trouble is that I have multiple production and test Apache servers, and I don’t want to hardcode them all.  They all have the same hostname, but I can’t find a way to do a wildcard for the port#.  What I got from Google, was to manually match against the calling host.  If it matches, simply parrot it back for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  The example I found returns null for me for the calling host.  Here’s what I found:

```
console.log(url.parse(req.url, true).host);
//should return 'myHostName:80', but I get null
```

Comment: The line of code you show seems correct. Maybe `req.url` is not what one would expect.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I can do about it?

Comment: What is `req.url` ?

Comment: req.url contains a forward slash and the query string from the URL.  If there isn't a query string, it contains just the forward slash.

Comment: I ended up just piping the Node webservice through my existing app.